# How to send a status message to my server when android activity get closed

Tags: java, android

My requirement is, I want to send a status to my server if my android application get closed or force quit. This requirement is to implement chat status, online or offline. How can i implement this?

Comment: Make connection to your server in onDestroy of your activity

Comment: send status to your server inside onDestroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do...

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    doSomething();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send status to your server when application closed or force quit then you should use override method onPause() because this method always guarantee to run if your app get closed or forcefully quit. Don't use onStop() because in case of force quit this method will not work. Don't use onDestroy() because this method will work when your activity will get destroyed.

```
@Override 
public void onPause() 
{
doSomething();
super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch controls on stopped applications

Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of controlling their launch from background processes and other applications.

Note that an application's stopped state is not the same as an Activity's stopped state. The system manages those two stopped states separately.

The platform defines two new intent flags that let a sender specify whether the Intent should be allowed to activate components in stopped application.

```
FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped applications in the list of potential targets to resolve against.
FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Exclude intent filters of stopped applications from the list of potential targets.
```

When neither or both of these flags is defined in an intent, the default behavior is to include filters of stopped applications in the list of potential targets.

Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications.

Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).